# Not able to get all the actions (View, Edit, Quick Edit, Trash), and not able to delete post in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

post_row_actions, This filter does not bring all the actions when I try to print_r

```
public function remove_quick_edit($actions) {

        global $post;

        echo "<pre>";
           print_r($actions);
        echo "</pre>"; 

        $link_get = get_delete_post_link($post->ID);

        if ( $post->post_type == 'cs_flags' ) {

            unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
            unset($actions['trash']);                           

            $actions['delete'] = '<span class="trash"><a class="submitdelete deletion" href="' . get_delete_post_link($post->ID, '', true) . '">' . esc_html__('Delete', 'jobhunt') . '</a></span>';                
        }

        return $actions;
    }
```

The result it brings is only views it should bring edit and trash also but only view is there.

I was debugging why get_delete_post_link not working, so I found this issue maybe they are related to each other.

http://prntscr.com/gxz0fu

Custom post type code

```
$args = array(
            'label' => __( 'Flags' ),
            'description' => esc_html__( 'This is Description' ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=jobs',
            'menu_position' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title' ),
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false,
        'delete_posts' => true
    )
        );
        register_post_type( 'cs_flags', $args );
    }
```

Comment: Can you please write you question in English. "Post row actions filter" is something ethereal.

Comment: `'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false,
        'delete_posts' => true
    )` is not the correct way to use this argument. It's probably interfering with your capabilities. Refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After some online searching I found a key to add in my arguments array of custom post type, `map_meta_cap => true` this brings the `View, Edit, Quick Edit, Trash` and that resolved my post delete issue also. I would like to recommend the following documentation who ever get stuck in such situation :)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type